# How do I set ISynchronizeInvoke to the Main Thread (SynchronizationContext.Current)?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, synchronization

I want to use the `System.Timers.Timer` inside of Unity, but Unity has a lot (a LOT) of functionality that only runs on the main thread. However, it uses an `ISynchronizeInvoke` property to determine on which thread the timer invokes its actions, and there is little to no information out there on how to force it to invoke on the main thread.

I've tried to set it to `SynchronizationContext.Current` but that doesn't work obviously. I've also simply tried to `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post` but that doesn't get called in Unity, or maybe I don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: why not use one of the many other methods properly documented with unity

Comment: In my particular use case, which methods do you mean? Note that we’re working in 2022.3 so we can’t use the Awaitable API yet.

Comment: So theres coroutines+waitfor, invoke, the traiditional float count down, for threading you can then add in the job system...

Comment: I know, but I wanted to build something more generic, something that works for Unity as well as .NET. It’s a shame because I have everything working, except that I don’t know how to invoke on the main thread.

Comment: Welcome to Casey’s world, where everything is harder than it needs to be ^w^”

Comment: Well, i googled and hit https://gist.github.com/JakubNei/90bf21be3fdc4829e631 does this not fill your void/scratch your itch?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, I owe you one! The GitHub wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it gave me a great insight into how ISynchronizeInvoke actually works (I couldn't find any examples before). If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: tbh what worries me more is that YOU didnt google it :P but then as you say why make your own life easier (hello, I also do this) - PS you could consider posting your solution on the unity asset store for others to buy (or for free)

Comment: I did Google it but I was looking for examples by Microsoft and scouring their documentation. I came at this from a whole different angle originally.

Comment: Well, I just googled unity and isynchronizeinvoke :P so yeah. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Much as I have not looked into ISynchroniszeInvoke, after a short discussion, Casey and I had established why and all the good things needed for a reasonable understanding of the issuee

My lack of knowledge lead me unsurprisingly to google, where I found [something on github](https://gist.github.com/JakubNei/90bf21be3fdc4829e631) which was at least in the right ball park.  While this is technically not a full answer, it clearly provided some missing information and may lead others who are also lacking to find the same.